# Find ordered combinations of search string letters in a haystack string (Hacker Rank challenge)

Tags: php, string, recursion, counting, substr

I tried (and failed) to complete a test from Hacker Rank.  The test asked to find how many `$newWord` exist in a `$oldWord`.

The letters do not need to be consecutive (they can have other characters in between), but they must be in order.

Example:

```
$newWord = 'abc';
$oldWord = 'abcababc';
```

How many occurency of `abc` exist here?

The answer is 7:

```
abcababc
^^^
abcababc
^^     ^
abcababc
^   ^  ^
abcababc
^     ^^
abcababc
   ^^  ^
abcababc
   ^  ^^
abcababc
     ^^^
```

I have tried many things like splitting into an array, `substr()`, `for()` loops, and `array_count_values()`, but I have not found the solution.

I don't understand the logic. For example, how can I find **a**bca**b**ab**c**?
What I tried:

- Split word into equal parts (from count `$newWord`) then count with array values but I only find two ways
- Remove one letter at a time and count `$newWord`

This's another example:

```
$newWord = 'ccc';
$oldWord = 'cccc';
```

How many occurences of `ccc` exist here?

The answer is 4:

```
cccc
^^^
cccc
^^ ^
cccc
^ ^^
cccc
 ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this challenge as an exercise in recursion.

Iterate the haystack and search for the characters that match only the first character in the needle string.  Upon finding a match, consume/remove the first character from the needle and all traversed letters in the haystack, then call the function again with the reduced strings.

When there is a match and no more needle characters to match, you add one to the total count.  At the end of the function, return the summed count.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CIt3i))

```
function countFoundSequences(string $needle, string $haystack): int
{
    if (!$needle) {
        return 0;
    }
    $tally = 0;
    $need = substr($needle, 0, 1);
    foreach (str_split($haystack) as $i => $straw) {
        if ($need === $straw) {
            if ($need === $needle) {
                ++$tally;
            } else {
                $tally += countFoundSequences(
                    substr($needle, 1),
                    substr($haystack, $i + 1)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $tally;
}
       
echo countFoundSequences('abc', 'abcababc');
// 7
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$newWord = 'abc';
$oldWord = 'abcababc';
$counter =0;

for ($a=0; $a<= strlen( $oldWord)-1; $a++){
    if($oldWord[$a]=='a'){
        for ($b=$a; $b<= strlen( $oldWord)-1; $b++){
            if($oldWord[$b]=='b'){
                for ($c=$b; $c<= strlen( $oldWord)-1; $c++){
                    if($oldWord[$c]=='c'){
                        $counter++;
                        print $counter.' abc<br>';
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is good, but if i put another example obv don't work, how can you done without know word, another example neword= 'ccc' oldword='cccc'

Comment: The code is easy to modify, just play with it.

Comment: You hardcode the word, in my case i can't